# syntax error, unexpected '$...' (T_VARIABLE) - Why?

Tags: php, bitrix

What's wrong with this code? I simplified the code as much as possible, but there is still an error

```
<?php

function createContact($arFields) {
 
    $newContactId = 0;
    return $newContactId;

}
```

Error shows VSCode and Local server PHP
[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoTPo.png)

Comment: Pasting that code into VSCode or a new file on a server doesn't show any error. It must be something different.

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS Code? Is OPCache maybe enabled on your server?

Comment: Don't paste simplified code but your exact, original code where the error appears

Comment: Nontransmittable syntax errors are usually based on Unicode whitespace. The code as posted here does not exhibit a syntax issues. So if the copy and paste is deemed good enough for posting here, why not just copy and paste it back into your editor?

Comment: Thanks! I reformatted whole code, and error has gone.